# Redirecting old site / subfolders to new site / subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am attempting to write some redirects and have stumbled on my final step of redirecting folders.

I have an old site with the following structure,

```
example.com
example.com/example
example.com/example/example
example.com/example/example
```

(with the domain examples.com parked and redirecting to this site)

And a new site (the domain unparked),

```
examples.com
examples.com/examples/new
examples.com/examples/examples/updated
examples.com/examples/examples/sample
```

Using a traditional 301 on the original site as per the below simply redirects to root

```
redirect 301 /example/ http:www.examples.com/examples/new/
```

it will not point to the correct subfolder

As a short term I have used the below to redirect all links to the root (on the old server) but it would be ideal to push them all to their exact locations

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/.*$ http://www.examples.com/
```

I'm obviously missing something simple so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /example(.*) http://examples.com/examples/new/$1
RedirectMatch 301 /example/example(.*) http://examples.com/examples/examples/$1
```

Example #1: http://oldsite.com/example/XXXX should redirect to http://newsite.com/examples/new/XXXX

Example #2: http://oldsite.com/example/example/UPDATE should redirect to http://newsite.com/examples/examples/UPDATE

ok if those above don't work..try this..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^example/?$ http://newsite.com/examples/new [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^example/example/([^/]+)/?$ http://newsite.com/examples/examples/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion but both still just dump me at the root directly

Comment: do you have this on top of ur htaccess file: `Options +FollowSymLinks` ?

Comment: Unfortunately adding this into my .htaccess still results in the urls redirecting to the root directory. - I'll keep looking thanks